# Centering an image on top of another one with Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, center

I would like to do this (my face in place of the white circle)[image]

But when I try, my face go on bottom.

Here is the code

```
`<div class="container-fluid no-padding">
        <div class="row">
             <div class="col-12">
                <img src="img/ordinateur.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <img src="img/moi.png" class="img-fluid">
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>`
```

Comment: use `ordianteur` as background ... with your code it's logical that it will go down

Comment: @Sam can you elaborate more on the issue?

Comment: @johnsackson I want my face at the middle of the background image.  I tried so many thinks, but everytimes I can't get exactly what I want. My issue is that my face go down the background

Comment: @Sam, I suppose, the blue with white circle should be displayed middle(vertically) is what the requirement is?

Comment: @johnsackson yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so now it's working.
I removed Bootstrap and just used flexbox.

the background in a flex container :

```
.container{
display: flex;
height: 300px;
background-image: url("../ordinateur.jpg");
}
```

the image:

```
.image{

width: 150px;
height: 150px;
margin: auto; /* center the image in the container */}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its better if you use the backdrop one as background image and you can shorten your code like the below. Here is the Codepen version: http://codepen.io/johnsackson/pen/GdpNoQ

```
  <div class="container no-padding">
    <div class="row background-img vmiddle">
      <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <img src="http://www.efusionsoft.com/ready2go/assets/2013/09/500x500-490x490.gif" class="img-fluid">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Styles:

```
.background-img {
  background: url(https://www.ledr.com/colours/red.jpg)
    0 0 no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
}

.vmiddle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: https://codepen.io/johnsackson/pen/OZyRvx, Can you check this and let me know if this is what you are looking at?

Answer (score 1):

You can use bootstrap if you add the class 'd-flex' and 'justify-content-center' to the parent div, they are built in Bootstrap 4 classes

Answer (score 0):

**Without Coding**
There are many ways to go about this. The one I would usually use (it's the most simple) is to simply edit the image using a photo editor and paste the face in the middle, and use THAT image as the background.

**With Coding** Another way to do this is shown below. All you have to do is look at the CSS styles that are attributes of each element, and copy them into your website.
http://simpodex.com/stackoverflowcontent/imageonimagetest.html

Comment: That's not me :p

Comment: gimme an image of you then

Comment: 1. gimme ordinateur image 2. gimme image of your face

Comment: oh yeah they also have to be a URL. And once your done and I change the pictures please mark the answer as correct.

Comment: also that was a placeholder... how am i supposed to know how you look like? you didnt even give me an image in the question...

Comment: @Sam did you see the comments above?